# Validating ReduxForm: Nested Values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form, redux-form-validators

I have validatioin in ReduxForm working until I have to validate a field whose name is nested ie: `location.coordinates[0]`.

This data looks like such in the Redux Store:

```
"location" : {
    "type" : "Point",
    "coordinates" : [ 
        103.8303, 
        4.2494
    ]
},
```

When trying to validate such fields using

**Approach 1**

```
if (!values.location.coordinates[0]) {
    errors.location.coordinates[0] = 'Please enter a longtitude';
}
```

I am getting error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'coordinates' of undefined

**Approach 2**

```
if (values.location !== undefined) {
    errors.location.coordinates[0] = 'Please enter a longtitude';
    errors.location.coordinates[1] = 'Please enter a latitude';
}
```

I am getting error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'coordinates' of undefined

**Question:** What is the proper way to handle such fields?

**/src/containers/Animals/AnimalForm.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
import { renderTextField } from './FormHelpers';

class AnimalForm extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={ this.props.handleSubmit }                     
                        <Field
                            label="Longitude"
                            name="location.coordinates[0]"
                            component={renderTextField}
                            type="text"
                        />                      
                        <Field
                            label="Latitude"
                            name="location.coordinates[1]"
                            component={renderTextField}
                            type="text"
                        />   
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

const validate = values => {
    let errors = {}

    if (values.location !== undefined) {
        errors.location.coordinates[0] = 'Please enter a longtitude';
        errors.location.coordinates[1] = 'Please enter a latitude';
    }
    if ((values.location !== undefined) && (values.location.coordinates !== undefined)) {
        errors.location.coordinates[0] = 'Please enter a longtitude';
        errors.location.coordinates[1] = 'Please enter a latitude';
    }

    return errors;
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { ... }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(reduxForm({
    form: 'animal',
    validate
})(AnimalForm))
```

**/src/containers/Animals/FormHelper.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { FormGroup, Label, Input, Alert } from 'reactstrap';

export const renderTextField = ({input, type, meta: {touched, error}, ...custom}) => (
    <div>
            <Label>{ label }</Label>
            <Input
                type={type}
                value={input.value}
                onChange={input.onChange}
            />
            {touched && error && <Alert color="warning">{ error }</Alert>}
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the validate method, how about structuring the initial errors object as such:

```
let errors = {
  location: {
    coordinates: []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below solution would work

```
const validate = values => {
    let errors = values;
    if(values){
        if (values.location) {
           errors.location.coordinates[0] = 'Please enter a longtitude';
           errors.location.coordinates[1] = 'Please enter a latitude';
        }
    }
        return errors;
 }
```

Comment: We have `let errors = {}` at the beginning of the validation function which is passed the `values` variable. Should we not check the `values` variable in the validation function?

Comment: @Nyxynyx Sorry I misunderstood your question. I have updated my answer now please give a try